# ValueError: Layer "model" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am new to TensorFlow and am trying to build a CNN model using MobileNet and ResNet architectures. When I compile the model and train it, I encounter this error. "ValueError: Layer "model" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None, None, None) dtype=float32>]"
what's done in this guide.

```
#this is my code
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV3Large, ResNet50V2
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate, Conv2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout

train_path = "trainpath"
test_path = "testpath"
valid_path = "validpath"

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True
)

train_data = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,
    target_size=(224,224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True
)

valid_data = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    valid_path,
    target_size=(224,224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True
)

test_data = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_path,
    target_size=(224,224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True
)

mobile_net = MobileNetV3Large(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
res_net = ResNet50V2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

mobile_net.trainable = False
res_net.trainable = False

mobile_net_output = mobile_net.output
res_net_output = res_net.output

concatenated = Concatenate()([mobile_net_output, res_net_output])

x = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(concatenated)
x = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)  # Dropout layer to reduce overfitting
x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)  # Dropout layer to reduce overfitting
x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)  
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x) 
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)  

model = Model(inputs=[mobile_net.input, res_net.input], outputs=output)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_data, validation_data = valid_data, epochs=15, batch_size=32, verbose=True)
```

Comment: you have to create a single input layer, otherwise the final model has 2 inputs

Comment: how to do it please ?

Comment: You can create 2 different model-train-fit sets for serving the purpose. It needs to be checked if the input takes a list or not. However for simplicity, it is suggested that you do the same. Hope it works , if its still valid to you.